# MySQL prints same record twice

Tags: php, mysql

**Update:**
Upon further investigation, it appears the file is being executed twice, as adding sample echo statements outside the while loop are printed twice as well.

---

I have a php file that is supposed to pull all of my site's users and display them (formatting will come later), but for some reason it appears to iterate through all the users twice. The `user_modify.php`file is run from another file, the code for which is shown below.

```
echo system("php templates/user_modify.php");
```

**templates/user_modify.php**

```
<?php

    include('php/connect.php');

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `email`,`name`,`class`,`verified`,`created` FROM users");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "Email: " . $row['email'] . "<br>";
            echo "Name: " . $row['name'] . "<br>";
            echo "Class: " . $row['class'] . "<br>";
            echo "Verified? " . ($row['verified'] === 0 ? "Yes" : "No") . "<br>";
            echo "Created on " . date("l, F jS, Y g:i a", strtotime($row['created'])) . "<br>";
        }
    }

?>
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php

    $conn = mysqli_connect("********************", "**********", "************", "**********");

?>
```

**What's Expected**

```
Email: email@example.com
Name: John Smith
Class: 2G
Verified? No
Created on Sunday, January 22nd, 2017 1:38 pm
Email: other_email@example.com
Name: Jimmy John
Class: 1B
Verified? No
Created on Monday, January 23rd, 2017 5:22 pm
```

**Actual Output**

```
Email: email@example.com
Name: John Smith
Class: 2G
Verified? No
Created on Sunday, January 22nd, 2017 1:38 pm
Email: other_email@example.com
Name: Jimmy John
Class: 1B
Verified? No
Created on Monday, January 23rd, 2017 5:22 pm
Email: email@example.com
Name: John Smith
Class: 2G
Verified? No
Created on Sunday, January 22nd, 2017 1:38 pm
Email: other_email@example.com
Name: Jimmy John
Class: 1B
Verified? No
Created on Monday, January 23rd, 2017 5:22 pm
```

Comment: Perhaps you have duplicates in the table.

Comment: Have you checked that you did not import the data twice and so the database has duplicates?

Comment: According to phpMyAdmin, only two records exist in the `users` table

Comment: @GordonLinoff any ideas? I manually inserted the only two rows that exist, so I know only two (with no duplicates) exist.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was having was echoing the return value of the `system` function. The `system` function echoes the computed data, and the additional `echo` statement echoes it for a second time.

Comment: Glad you solved the issue! It's not a bad idea to check up on [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) to see if a function will print something or return something.